# Collapsing categorical variables with many levels with respect to target

Tags: python, r, categorical-data, lasso-regression

I am trying to apply a methodology to collapse/fuse (not just select part of them) some levels of categorical variables, considering their impact on a continuos target variable. I've come across [this great post on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/146907), where the [accepted answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/237000) provides an interesting technique based on Lasso penalties that I would like to apply. The methodology is explained in detail in the paper [*Sparse modeling of categorial explanatory variables (Gertheiss and Tutz, 2010)*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-statistics/volume-4/issue-4/Sparse-modeling-of-categorial-explanatory-variables/10.1214/10-AOAS355.full).

However, I have not found any code/libraries that would allow me to apply this methodology in Python (or eventually R). I was wondering if someone could share some hints or sources that I could use to replicate this technique.

I am also open to apply other techniques to assess my issue. Thanks.

I have tried to replicate from scratch the methodology from the paper but it seems too hard for me.